# Can you return a Boolean value in loop in this condition

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, boolean

I hope someone can answer this for me. Is there a way in JavaScript that we can use a loop with an "if" statement inside  and only return true if all the values in the loop iterations meet that condition. Thank you

Comment: `for (…) { if (!condition) return false; } return true`

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is. For example the [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method of an Array does this exact thing.
Quoted from MDN:

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```js
const ages = [24, 32, 22, 21, 29];
const legalDrinkingAge = 21;
const areLegalDrinkingAges = ages.every(age => age >= legalDrinkingAge);

console.log(areLegalDrinkingAges);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a var, e.g. `result` holding the value `true`, then executing the for loop and checking the condition using the `if` statement. Once condition fails, set `result` to `false` and break out of the `for` loop.

At the end, `result` will be `true` if the `if` statement was true for all elements checked and `false` otherwise.

```
var result = true;
var a = [12,14,16,18,5,11,12];   // array with example values
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) {
    if (!(a[i] >= 10)) {  // the condition
        result = false;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(result); // false
```

Comment: Thanks. Made sense!